# Webhook for Portal event - Keyrequest

Tags: portal, tyk

Want to use keycloak to authenticate and generate a key when a dev logins into the portal and requests for a key. The https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-developer-portal/tyk-portal-classic/portal-events-notifications/ documentation talks about Portal event that could trigger a webhook to do the same. Is there any example info to share?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the [Key cloak DCR docs](https://tyk.io/docs/nightly/tyk-developer-portal/tyk-portal-classic/keycloak-dcr/) for authenticating developers?

The webhook looks to be an organization wide trigger. As the doc mentions, an additional property `event_options` is needed when creating or updating an organization.

Demo org details

[image: 2]

The [doc](https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-developer-portal/tyk-portal-classic/portal-events-notifications/#extra-dashboard-and-portal-events) mentions where to add it and what each field means. However, it does not specify if multiple webhooks are possible for a single field. So it might be worth taking note of that.